# GWT - Facebook comments - View more

Tags: facebook, gwt, facebook-comments

I've almost successfully integrated facebook comments in my application, but there are some problems that I don't know how to resolve.

The problem is that the button/div "View More X" comments and the superior bar (where we can select the order by) do not appear.

You can see in this link:
http://saxbox.keep.pt/community/#id/5

There are 6 or 7 comments, the plugin has a maximum of 5 comments but the button view more doesn't appear.

Any suggestions?

---

I've created a HTML file to test the Facebook plugin with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html> <!--xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js#xfbml=1";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://saxbox.keep.pt/community/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
</html>
```

Even with this simple HTML I didn't get the view more button. There is any bug with the plugin? or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When facebook tries to lint the page there might be a problem.

It could be something to do with the hash tag in the url.  Is there a way to convert over to a querystring instead?

When I first went to that page in a clean browser, I did not get to the id 5 page, but was redirected to some homepage.  I then had to retype the #id/5 to get to the real page...Facebook is probably running into the same situation.

**EDIT**

Ok, I tried again and facebook still sees wrong information:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsaxbox.keep.pt%2Fcommunity%2F%23id%2F5

And if you follow this link:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsaxbox.keep.pt%2Fcommunity%2F%23id%2F5

This is what your server responds with: Notice there are no og meta tags and there's no comment plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- The HTML 4.01 Transitional DOCTYPE declaration--><!-- above set at the top of the file will set     --><!-- the browser's rendering engine into           --><!-- "Quirks Mode". Replacing this declaration     --><!-- with a "Standards Mode" doctype is supported, --><!-- but may lead to some differences in layout.   --><html>
<!-- xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">--><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- Default locale --><meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=pt_PT">
<!--                                                               --><!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files --><!--                                                               --><!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="WebCommunityClient.css">--><title>weebox community</title>
<!--                                           --><!-- This script loads your compiled module.   --><!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   --><!-- be added before this line.                --><!--                                           --><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="webcommunityclient/webcommunityclient.nocache.js"></script><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="rss">
<meta name="title" content="weebox community">
<meta name="description" content="weebox community">
<link rel="image_src" href="logo.png">
</head>
<!--                                           --><!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      --><!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  --><!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        --><!--                                           --><body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support --><iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0"></iframe>

<div id="loading" style="height: 99%;"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." style="position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -27px; margin-left: -27px;"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read my edit. Even with a simple URL the plugin is not working correctly. Any suggestion?

Comment: See edited comments above.  You must fix it so facebook can Lint the page AND you must fix the url as well.

Comment: The og meta tags are something that I can add quickly.
Why it gives the code 206? Because of the non existence of og meta tags?

Comment: The 206 is being sent from your server, not from facebook's server.  You should fix that as well as ensuring your url has a canonical link too.

Comment: Sorry to only give feedback now, but I only had time to see this now.
I have develloped an servlet that resolves canonical links into the link with the anchor. So the problem with canonical link is solved.

The servlet gives an HTML with facebook tags, which after some time redirects to link with the anchor.
Ex: http://saxbox.keep.pt/community/id/5 redirects to  http://saxbox.keep.pt/community/#id/5

But i'm still having the code 206 and I don't know why. I think that is code 206 that is somehow blocking the view more button.